# DateTimePicker Format

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, datetimepicker

I have a problem with the DateTimePicker. I am new to C# and developing a standalone application with MS Access 2007 as my DB.

I have a DateTimePicker (dtp_btime) with Format as "Time" and Custom Format "hh:mm tt".
No doubt it can display as "10:30 pm". But when I click on save it obviously saved both the Date and Time in the DB table.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "insert into Booking(cname, bdate, btime, ccontact, sname) Values('" + txt_cname.Text + "','" + dtp_bdate.Value.Date + "','" + dtp_btime.Value + "','" + txt_ccontact.Text + "','" + txt_sname.Text + "')";
```

How can I only save the time without the date from the DateTimePicker?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks,

Do you mind to point the right way? And how does it tell you the possibilities of SQL injection?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a text field in access, you should be able to use

```
dtp_btime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

If it's not, then just store date and time as-is and display just the time portion in your reports or wherever it's displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works once I change the DataType in DB to Text and add your lines in the insertion statement.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with the DateTimePicker, it's a problem with the database datetime type.  The database stores a date and time together.  You can force it save with a date of 01/01/0001 or something like that for every column if you want.  I don't know if Access has a datatype that only stores time, but I would doubt it.

Comment: Access has no data storage - it is the development platform. By "Access" you surely mean its default database engine, Jet/ACE. There is only one date/time data type, and it stores both date and time at all times (it's stored as a double, where the date is the integer part and the time is the decimal part).

Comment: You are correct, saying JET would probably have been more accurate, but doubt most people who do their development in access understand the distinction =).